# Reading an excel file using cordova in ios

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova, alasql

I am currently working on a hybrid app for iOS. I am using Ionic/Cordova to make it. It's my first time using it.

I want to be able to read an xlsx file that is currently on my iPad and show that data in my app in a table format. I have read about the ngCordova file plugin at http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/. I have also read about AlaSQL.js at https://github.com/agershun/alasql. Can I use these together to do my task? Or should I use one over the other?

I find the documentation for the file plugin to be a bit confusing. Can someone give me a pointer or example of accessing the file and outputting it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try to use file plugin to retrieve directory list and fileOpener2 plugin to open xlsx file.